# Returning a shared_ptr from a function

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, auto

I'm very new to C++11, 'still very much experimenting with the extensions. I find the `auto` keyword very convenient, particularly when dealing with template variables. This means that given

```
template<typename ... Types>
struct Foo
{
};

template<typename ... Types>
Foo<Types ...>* create( Types ... types ... )
{
    return new Foo<Types ...>;
}
```

I can now make the assignment

```
auto t1 = create( 'a' , 42 , true , 1.234 , "str" );
```

instead of

```
Foo<char, int, bool, double , const char*>* t2 = create( 'a' , 42 , true , 1.234 , "str" );
```

The problem now is that because `t1` is a pointer I'd like to hold it in a `shared_ptr` as Herb Sutter recommended. Therefore, I'd like to store the return value of `create()` in a `shared_ptr` without having to name the template argument types, as in `t2`.

Comment: Do you mean `std::shared_ptr<Foo<Types ...> >`? It doesn't work.

Comment: There is no such thing as "an `auto`". See, this is why I disagreed with the proposal.

Comment: `auto` is not a type, so the wording of the question is not really sensible. I'm pointing this out not to nitpick but because it suggests that you need to read up more on it to understand how it works.

Comment: What @fish said. It's easy to sound like an ass when pointing this sort of thing out, but it's genuinely done for good reason.

Comment: It's now very non-specific :(

Comment: Please feel free to edit the title.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using raw pointers all together. Use `std::make_shared` and `make_unique` (not right in the standard) instead of `new`. Then `auto` will work nicely. E.g.

```
template <typename ...Args>
auto create(Args&&... args)
    -> std::shared_ptr<Foo<typename std::decay<Args>::type...>>
{
    return std::make_shared<Foo<typename std::decay<Args>::type...>>(
        std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<Foo<Types...>>`

Comment: Is `-> std::shared_ptr<Types...>` really part of the signature?

Comment: @Olumide: Yes, but it's *entirely* unnecessary to use a [late-specified return type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Alternative_function_syntax) here.

Comment: Are the `...`s part of the actual code that you would compile?

Answer (score 0):

*This is too long to post as a comment. Therefore I'm posting it here instead. Besides it might be an answer.*

@nosid why not the following. Its less convoluted.

```
template<typename ... Types>
struct Foo
{
    Foo( Types ... types ... ) : m_data( types ...)
    {
    }

    std::tuple<Types...>    m_data;
};

template<typename ... Types>
std::shared_ptr<Foo<Types ...> > create( Types ... types ... )
{
    return std::make_shared<Foo<Types ...> >( types ... );
}
```